# What should I do with my functions that return wrong answers?

Tags: c, trigonometry, exp

**We could not use math.h**

I get wrong answers in cases with inputs greater than 54 in my sine function and inputs greater than 37 in my exp functions; I guess it overflows, what should I do?
I want to write sine function and exp function on my own and I use Taylor expansion. And I just need 6 digits in the fraction;

```
    //Start of exp function
float exp(float x)
{
    double expreturn=0;
    long long int fctrl=1;
    for(int n=0;n<=12;n++){

        fctrl=1;
        for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
            fctrl *= i;
        expreturn += (pow(x,n)/fctrl);

    }

    return (float)expreturn;
}//End of exp function



//Start of sin function
float sin(float x)
{
    double sinus=0;
    long long int fctrl=1;
   while(!(0<=x&&x<6.3))
    {
        if(x<0)
            x += PI*2;
        else
            x -= PI*2;

    }
    for(int n=0;n<=8;n++)
    {
        fctrl=1;
        for(int i=2;i<=(2*n+1);i++)
            fctrl *= i;
       sinus += ((pow(-1,n)*pow(x,2*n+1))/fctrl);
    }
    return (float)sinus;
}//End of sin function


//Start of pow function
float pow(float x,int y)
{
    double pow = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<y;i++)
        pow *= x;
    return (float)pow;
}//End of pow Function
```

Here are some examples:

**Input**

> sin(200)

**Desired output**

> -0.873297

**My function output**

> -0.872985

But it works properly with small values

I use this:

[image: Here is my method]

What Could I do now?

Comment: `I get wrong answers in some cases in my functions;` for which cases you get which answers and how do you "get" those answers and how do you check those answers and how are they wrong?

Comment: How do you define "wrong answer"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: On a cursory glance, is `sinus` initialised?

Comment: Please give some examples of the wrong and desired values. Also, something to keep in mind (sometimes is the case on such math): If you perform computation between two INTs, it does not matter whether you store the result in a double or float, the result will be floored to the next integer anyways. I would always implement math algorithms first with doubles only instead of INTs to be safe. Once this works, you can optimize back to INTs.

Comment: I suggest to add a `main` functions that demonstrates with hard-coded values how to get a good case and a bad case for every function you are having problems with.

Comment: Is the PI you use, accurate enough? Aka as accurate as it fits into a double, I mean.

Comment: @AlexGeorg Yep, It has 26 digit accuracy in fractions

Comment: The value you are using for π is not accurate to 26 digits. If you are using a common C implementation and are using `double` for `PI`, then it differs from π by at least 1.22e-16, because closest value to π that is representable in the format commonly used for `double` is that far from π. If you are using `float`, it is at least 8.74e-8 away from π. And, even if `PI` is `double`, you are using `float` to reduce the function argument `x`.

Comment: I [cannot](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3c6i4l520A5X9mMh) reproduce (warnings apart). Also, here `0<=x&&x<6.3`, is that `6.3` supposed to be 2PI?

Comment: Do not name your functions `sin`, `pow`, or `exp`. Those names are reserved for the C standard library functions.

Comment: @Bob__: With `-O2`, Clang evaluates `sin(200)` at compile time, using a built-in `sin` rather than the one in the source code.

Comment: Unless you have peculiar requirements, use `double` everywhere, not `float`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, [my bad](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gRD4PQNwWZoPoQp3). Thanks.

Comment: Adding more terms to the series brings the output closer to the expected value. The error in the series grows with larger values of `x`, so larger errors with larger arguments are expected, especially with few terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to increase the accuracy of the posted code.

- Using `double` as preferred type, instead on `int` and `float`, for variables storing intermediates, arguments and result.
- Take advantage of the symmetry of the function to limit the calculations in the range where the numerical approximation is more accurate.
  The `sin` function, for example, could be implemented using two function, an entry point which transforms the angle passed as argument and corrects the result of the other function implementing the series computation:

```
const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846264338; // It will be rounded, anyway.
const double TAU = PI * 2;
const double HALF_PI = PI / 2;
const double THREE_HALF_PI = PI * 1.5;

// This is called only for x in [-Pi/2, Pi/2]
double my_sin_impl(double x);

double my_sin(double x)
{
    // I want to transform all the angles in the range [-pi/2, 3pi/2]
    if ( x < -HALF_PI )
    {
        long long y = (THREE_HALF_PI - x) / TAU;
        x += y * TAU;
    }
    if ( x > THREE_HALF_PI )
    {
        long long y = (x + HALF_PI) / TAU;
        x -= y * TAU;
    }

    if ( x < HALF_PI )
        return my_sin_impl(x);
    else                              //    When x is in [pi/2, 3pi/2],
        return -my_sin_impl(x - PI);  // <- the result should be transformed
}
```

- Unless it's mandatory for the assignment, avoid using `pow` directly and calculating the factorial at every iteration. It's inefficient and could lead to overflow with integer types. See, e.g. the following implementation of a different approach.
- In the posted code, the number of iterations to calculate `sin` is fixed to 8, but we can stop when the numerical accuracy of the type is reached. In the following snippet I've also splitted the sum of terms with alternating signs into two partial sums, to limit (slightly) the [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).

```
double my_sin_impl(double x)
{
    double old_positive_sum, positive_sum = x;
    double old_negative_sum, negative_sum = 0.0;
    double x2 = x * x;
    double term = x;
    int n = 2; 
    do
    {
        term *= x2 / (n * (n + 1));
        old_negative_sum = negative_sum;
        negative_sum += term;
        term *= x2 / ((n + 2) * (n + 3));
        old_positive_sum = positive_sum;
        positive_sum += term;
        n += 4;
    }
    while (positive_sum != old_positive_sum  &&  negative_sum != old_negative_sum);
    //                  ^^ The two values are still numerically different 
    return positive_sum - negative_sum;
}
```

Otherwise, noticing that the loop in the previous snippet is executed at most 5 times (give or take), we can decide to keep the number of titerations fixed and precalculate the coefficients. Something like this (testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CMv0MjvIaRihmPnr)).

```
double my_sin_impl(double x)
{
    static const double k_neg[] = {1.0/ 6.0, 1.0/42.0, 1.0/110.0, 1.0/210.0, 1.0/342.0};
    static const double k_pos[] = {1.0/20.0, 1.0/72.0, 1.0/156.0, 1.0/272.0, 1.0/420.0};

    double positive_sum = 0.0;
    double negative_sum = 0.0;
    double x2 = x * x;
    double term = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
    {
        term *= x2 * k_neg[i];
        negative_sum += term;
        term *= x2 * k_pos[i];
        positive_sum += term;
    }
    return x * (1.0 + positive_sum - negative_sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you calculate 'x modulus 2 PI' in `sin()` doesn't produce accurate results, e.g. with `x = 200` you get 5.221206 whilst `fmod()` returns 5.221255.

Making `x` a `double` instead of `float` solved that inaccuracy for me.

That's the code I've tested with. It has produced the same results wihtout optimization or with `-O3` on `gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI  3.14159265358979323846264338

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    double v = strtod( argv[1], 0 );
    float  f;
    double d;

    f = v;
    while( f > 6.3 ) {
        f -= 2*PI;
    }

    d = v;
    while( d > 6.3 ) {
        d -= 2*PI;
    }

    printf( "%f\n", f );
    printf( "%lf\n", d );
    printf( "%lf\n", fmod( v, 2*PI ) );
    return( 0 );
}
```

**Edit**

As @Eric Postpischil@ has pointed out, that still doesn't explain the false results, so 'Ive staretd playing around with `sin()` itself, and it seems increasing the number of iterations can increase accuracy.
Making `fctrl` an `unsigned long long` you can iterate up to n=10 without  overflowing and for x=200 or x=5.221255 you will now get the result -0.873260
which is at least closer.

That's the actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI  3.14159265358979323846264338

int iter = 8;
//Start of sin function
float mysin(double x)
{
    double sinus=0;
    unsigned long long int fctrl=1;
    while(!(0<=x&&x<6.3))
    {
        if(x<0)
            x += PI*2;
        else
            x -= PI*2;

    }
    for(int n=0;n<=iter;n++)
    {
        fctrl=1;
        for(int i=2;i<=(2*n+1);i++)
            fctrl *= i;

        double pr = (pow(-1,n)*pow(x,2*n+1));
        printf( "%lf / %llu\n", pr, fctrl );
        sinus += pr / fctrl;
    }
    return (float)sinus;
}//End of sin function

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    double v = strtod( argv[1], 0 );
    if( argc > 2 ) {
        iter = strtol( argv[2], 0, 10 );
    }
    float  f;
    double d;

    f = v;
    while( f > 6.3 ) {
        f -= 2*PI;
    }

    d = v;
    while( d > 6.3 ) {
        d -= 2*PI;
    }

/*
    printf( "%f\n", f );
    printf( "%lf\n", d );
    printf( "%lf\n", fmod( v, 2*PI ) );
*/

    printf( "%f\n", mysin( v ) );
    return( 0 );
}
```

**Edit 2**

Another improvement is to avoid calculating x ^ (2n+1) and n! first (which will produce huge values) and then divide but use a loop like that:

```
for(int n=0;n<=iter;n++)
{
    double v = n % 2 == 0 ? 1.0 : -1.0;
    for( int j=1; j <= 2*n+1; j++ ) {
            v *= x;
            v /= j;
    }
    sinus += v;
}
```

With n=10, `mysin(200)` returns -0.873296 now

Comment: @EricPostpischil it's included now. But my test script returns the same values with or without optimization

Comment: please note that I've only analyzed the modulus part. That idea came to me because of "But it works properly with small values"

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right of course. The statement, that the code worked for small values misled me to the assumption that the problem could be in the modulus part only. I've now played around with `sin()` itself and posted the result in an edit

Comment: @EricPostpischil finally I think I have found a satisfying solution